# attempting to reset local branch with code and files from remote branch not working

Tags: git, visual-studio

I had a branch of my code called local_development_efcore. I then committed changes to this branch as I knew I was about to do something experimental, then created a new local branch called local_development_efcore_scaffold and tracked it remotely as well. I added some code to this branch. I then wanted to back out from this local_development_efcore_scaffold entirely. I just want to go back to my old branch.

I switched to checking out a different branch - master. So I could then delete local_development_efcore_scaffold both remotely and locally. I then switched to local_development_efcore expecting the code I'd added to be gone, but it's still there. My additional classes etc. I would like to force GIT to simply take my originally committed local_development_efcore from the remote origin, and bring it down, and make my local working branch of the same name, have the exact same code, without any of my additions. Can anyone assist?

This is what I did to get rid of my experimental branch:

Delete remove branch

PM> git push origin --delete local_development_efcore_scaffold

Checkout a different branch so your local target branch is unchecked

PM> git checkout local_development_efcore

Then delete

PM> git branch -D local_development_efcore_scaffold

But I expected to be able to select my original local_development_efcore branch and have my added classes etc gone, but they were still there, even after using:

PM> git reset --hard origin/local_development_efcore
HEAD is now at 4f163d1 Commit pre attempt to force scaffold update
PM> git fetch

Comment: Did you push to `local_develope_efcore` after you "committed changes to this branch"? Anyway, you can try `git reflog local_develope_efcore`. It will tell you which commit the branch had been before you committed changes to `local_develope_efcore`. After you get the commit, you can run `git checkout local_development_efcore;git reset <that_commit> --hard` to reset the branch.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a branch is just removing a pointer: you won't see any commit referenced by it, but you will still see any other commit referenced by *another branch* (or tag)

```
 x--x--x--x (local_development_efcore)
           \
            y--y--y (local_development_efcore_scaffold)

 git branch -D local_development_efcore_scaffold

 x--x--x--x (local_development_efcore)
```

If you still see code done for scaffolding,... may be it was:

- not committed (and the current working tree work in progress remains visible)
- or committed on the wrong branch (`local_development_efcore`)

If that scaffolding code is present in 4f163d1 (`git show 4f163d1`), try at least to reset to the commit preceding 4f163d1.